# Template Hierarchy for custom post type pages

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, themes

So I have a custom post type that is called `recipe` and then I have a page called `/recipes/` - What would be the proper way to hook a template for my recipes page?

I have the file `single-recipe.php` following the WordPress hierarchy with this inside:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Recipe
Template Post Type: post, page
*/

echo 'Hello';
```

But I'm not getting any templating output:
[image]

The below is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename `single-recipe.php` is telling WordPress "only use this file to display single 'recipe' CPT posts."

If you want to use it as a Page template, you can either rename the file `tpl-recipe.php` (or something similar, it doesn't have to be this filename, it just has to not be a recognized pattern like `single-cptslug.php`) - in which case you'll have to manually choose that template every time you create a new Recipe -

Or, you can have two files. One named `single-recipe.php` which does NOT have the comments at the top, and one named `tpl-recipe.php` (or similar) which DOES have the comments at the top.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it had to be a WordPress hierarchy template name, thanks a bunch @WebElaine - I'll rename it soon.